# How do I get a coefficient matrix from a second order ODE's system?

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, eigenvalues

I got this system:

[image]

I  need to transform this ODE system in a matrix form, because I need to evaluate its stability and, further, plot the eigensystem with the Stream Plot function.
Is there any command that, automatically, transform an ODE system into a matrix?

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please load a minimal example with Mathematica code that can be copied, pasted and executed locally in our own notebook sessions. It is difficult to offer concrete advice in the absence of usable code. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
x^{\prime\prime}  & =\frac{k_{2}}{m_{1}}y-\frac{k_{1}+k_{2}}{m_{1}}x\\
y^{\prime\prime}  & =\frac{k_{2}}{m_{2}}x-\frac{k_{3}+k_{2}}{m_{2}}y
\end{align*}

Let $x_{1}=x,x_{2}=x^{\prime},x_{3}=y,x_{4}=y^{\prime}$, hence

\begin{align*}
x_{1}^{\prime}  & =x_{2}\\
x_{2}^{\prime}  & =x^{\prime\prime}=\frac{k_{2}}{m_{1}}x_{3}-\frac{k_{1}%
+k_{2}}{m_{1}}x_{1}\\
x_{3}^{\prime}  & =x_{4}\\
x_{4}^{\prime}  & =y^{\prime\prime}=\frac{k_{2}}{m_{2}}x_{1}-\frac{k_{3}%
+k_{2}}{m_{2}}x_{3}%
\end{align*}

In Matrix form $x^{\prime}=Ax$ becomes

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}^{\prime}\\
x_{2}^{\prime}\\
x_{3}^{\prime}\\
x_{4}^{\prime}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
-\frac{k_{1}+k_{2}}{m_{1}} & 0 & \frac{k_{2}}{m_{1}} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\frac{k_{2}}{m_{2}} & 0 & -\frac{k_{3}+k_{2}}{m_{2}} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
x_{3}\\
x_{4}%
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Using Mathematica, just use `StateSpaceModel` and it will do it all for you. It will also give you the input, output and transmission matrices as well. You do not have any input in your ode's. If you had them, you will see the rest also.

```
ode1=x1''[t]==(k2/m1)*x2[t]-(k1+k2)/m1*x1[t]
ode2=x2''[t]==(k2/m2)*x1[t]-(k3+k2)/m2*x2[t]

ss = StateSpaceModel[{ode1, 
   ode2}, {{x1[t], 0}, {x1'[t], 0}, {x2[t], 0}, {x2'[t], 0}}, {}, {x1[
    t], x2[t]}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you had input in your ode's, then do this

```
ode1 = x1''[t] == (k2/m1)*x2[t] - (k1 + k2)/m1*x1[t] + u[t]
ode2 = x2''[t] == (k2/m2)*x1[t] - (k3 + k2)/m2*x2[t]

ss = StateSpaceModel[{ode1, 
   ode2}, {{x1[t], 0}, {x1'[t], 0}, {x2[t], 0}, {x2'[t], 0}}, {{u[t], 
    0}}, {x1[t], x2[t]}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StateSpaceModel.html

Remember that in control systems/state space we have

\begin{align*}
   x' &=A x + B u\\
   y  &=C x + D u
\end{align*}

Where $x$ are the state variables, and $u$ is the input to the system and $y$ is the output.

And Mathematica output above gives these $A,B,C,D$ all in one output matrix that you see there. So you have to read them in the order they show.

In most practical application $D$ will be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Using `CoefficientArrays`:

```
eqns = {Subscript[x, 1]'[t] == Subscript[x, 2][t], 
Subscript[x, 2]'[t] == (Subscript[k, 2]/Subscript[m, 1])*
Subscript[x, 3][t] - ((Subscript[k, 1] + Subscript[k, 2])/
Subscript[m, 1])*Subscript[x, 1][t], 
Subscript[x, 3]'[t] == Subscript[x, 4][t], 
Subscript[x, 4]'[t] == (Subscript[k, 2]/Subscript[m, 2])*
Subscript[x, 1][t] - ((Subscript[k, 3] + Subscript[k, 2])/
Subscript[m, 2])*Subscript[x, 3][t]};(*Thanks, Nasser!*)

coeffs = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eqns, {Subscript[x, 1][t], 
Subscript[x, 2][t], Subscript[x, 3][t], Subscript[x, 4][t]}]
```

[image]

Next, we verify that we are correct:

```
eqns2 = Thread[coeffs[[1]] == (-coeffs[[2]]) . {Subscript[x, 1][t], 
        Subscript[x, 2][t], Subscript[x, 3][t], Subscript[x, 4][t]}] // Simplify

eqns2 === (eqns // Simplify)
(*True*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking what you have done aboove in your ask, I did it (turn a 2nd order ODE system in 4 equations 1st order ODE system). But, as I said, I need to comper this 2 situations (2nd order ODE system, being composed by 2 equations and, in other hand, the way you described above).

This kind of solution you past, will work for both cases (making the necessary changes?).

Despite all of I reported here, thank you so much for your answer.

I did the 4 equations 1st order ode system manually, like this:

[image]

Beacause further, as I did for the just solution form (DSolveValue with innitial conditions, Manipulate and Animate) I will need to do the same process after que stability system analysis for 2nd order ODE system (2 equations) and 1st order system (4 equations).

```
    Manipulate[
 Plot[SolucaoEspecifica /. {X1 -> XX1, X2 -> XX2, 
    Subscript[m, 1] -> M1, Subscript[m, 2] -> M2, 
    Subscript[k, 1] -> K1, Subscript[k, 2] -> K2, 
    Subscript[k, 3] -> K3}, {t, 0, 10},PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-5, 5}}], {K1, 1, 4}, {K2, 1, 4}, {K3, 1, 4}, {XX1, -1, 1}, {XX2, -1, 1}, {M1, 1, 3}, {M2, 1, 3}]; 
    Animate[Manipulate[
  Plot[SolucaoEspecificaMassaCte /. {X1 -> XX1, X2 -> XX2, 
     Subscript[k, 1] -> K1, Subscript[k, 2] -> K2, 
     Subscript[k, 3] -> K3}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-3, 3}}], {K1, 1, 3}, {K2, 1, 3}, {K3, 1, 3}, {XX1, -0.5, 0.5}, {XX2, -0.5, 0.5}]]
```

Comment: For the case of the two equations, use `CoefficientArrays`. At first, I did it like this.

Comment: In the `Eigensystem` documentation, you'll find a pertinent example addressing what you're seeking, particularly for analyzing a second-order equation system.